# how to set value in Option onchange selection in Jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.jsp" name="productForm">

        </select> <select name="colour" onchange="document.productForm.submit()">
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="white">White</option>
            <option value="brown">Brown</option>
        </select>
    <form>

        <%
            String colour = request.getParameter("colour");
            out.println(colour);
        %>

</body>
</html>
```

This My Source code of index.jsp when i select change then it pass value to console and Print it But onSelect drop down Value is not set it set to first value please help me how to set value in Obation also

Answer (score 0):

No on page load the drop down refreshes.So your previous option wont assign to it any more .

What you  can do is ,Assign the parameter to a `Js varaible` and On `document ready` assign it to your drop down using javascript.